# crawling javascript drop down lists

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I'm trying to make an infographic on COVID for my school to raise awareness. The problem I ran into was the web page didn't have the information as text. Instead, the drop down was made by javascript.

This is the site: https://www.nga.org/coronavirus-state-actions-all/#NE

What are some ways I can potentially parse this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When crawling web sites with JavaScript enabled, it's probably best to do it in a browser context.

1. You could either go to the site and paste your script into the console once it's loaded and use `copy(result)` to copy the result of your script into the clipboard.
2. Use [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) in NodeJS to automate a browser session. Puppeteer is a headless Chrome that can evaluate JavaScript and you could leverage NodeJS to write the crawled results into a file.

Depending on how often you need to do this (and how often the site changes its markup which you select), it might be faster/easier to implement option 1 first, even if it's only half-automated.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on option one? What kind of script would I need to paste into the browser?

Comment: What information do you want to crawl from the page exactly? The script would be something like `document.querySelectorAll("some-element > div.some-class .class-of-item")` and mapping these elements to whatever you want to have as result

Comment: After looking at the page again, I don't see why to wait for JavaScript to finish loading. When downloading the page with `curl`, it has all information available in its source code. and it only needs to be parsed into whatever you need. Maybe state what you need from the page and I can tell you what I would do or use in order to achieve that. Would that help?